# How to Install Kali Linux on Windows 8 With BCD instead of Grub

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, grub, bcd, kali-linux

I have Windows 8.1 64-bit installed on my PC. I have been trying to install Kali Linux using its ISO and Universal USB Installer (1.9.5.2) using a USB drive  since the CD drive won't work.

The problem is that the Setup will either overwrite my Windows MBR and install Grub which I don't want; I want my Windows 8.1 Bootloader but with the Kali installation for boot up.

Is there any workaround for this ? I have tried BCDedit but it provided no help (maybe I was wrong somewhere, that's why). A good explanation with the answer would be really helpful.

NOTE : Before Kali I used BackTrack and Ubuntu with the "Install inside Windows" option that came within the installation procedure while running Setup.exe .
This time when I run Setup.exe (for Kali) the following error shows up :

[image: This program doesn't support Windows 6.2.9200 SP0 yet.]

If I would be able to install Kali inside Windows (like Ubuntu), that would be even better.

Any help is appreciated :) . Thanks in advance !

EDIT : The reason for not removing the BCD and using GRUB is :

[image: BootScreen]

So that I can install Windows directly from my boot screen via my hardrive without having to do anything else (PS : I modified the BCD using BCDEdit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install kali linux on seperate partition.

When ask to install grub on MBR, select no, then write name of the linux boot partition eg:/dev/sda5.

Kali will install the grub into that partition without overwriting the windows bootLoader.
Now loginto windows and use EasyBCD tool to add Kali linux on Windows Boot menu.

But this will give you old windows 7 style menu back.
Start the EasyBCD tool and under utilities section open console and type 
"bcdboot c:\windows"
This will bring the graphical boot menu.

By the way EasyBCD is free for non-comercial use.

Comment: Could you rather elaborate on the "use EasyBCD tool to add Kali linux on Windows Boot menu" part? Because it's rather annoying with all the 'Grub' options (I am not that comfortable with it, you see). Thanks in advance.  
By the way, I am using BCD for non-commercial use :)

Answer (score 2):

Message is straight forward. 
They don't support win8.1 for now (for automation of t his procedure)

this is what you need
[Debian & Windows 8.1 Dual Boot](https://superuser.com/questions/714856/trying-to-dual-boot-windows-8-1-and-debian-jessie)
You can try that or wait for official support with the installer

Comment: But any idea when the official support would come out ?
The link is for Grub which I don't want, I wanted BCD instead. But thanks anyways.

Comment: For now, there is no way to BCD from w8 see debian (Kali). So dual bot with GRUB or Dual boot from live cd ;)

Answer (score 0):

Left click on Linux Kali setup select properties than select compatibility choose compatibility mode as Windows 7

You are done 
Now try to install kali